# Transaction Propagation in EJBs methods

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, remote-access

I want to make sure to understand corrsctly transaction propagation,please help.

Let's suppose we have a stateless **EJB_A** wich exposes the services of the application tier.

it uses local stateless **EJB_B** , **EJB_C** ,
both of them use a container managed **EntityManager**.
**EJB_B** and **EJB_C** use eachother methods.

If I understand things correctly each EJB gets it own intsance of an EntityManager to the manage same persistence unit.

Let's suppose **EJB_A**, on a client request, uses methods of bot EJB_B and EJB_C to create a transaction for example:

```
@Stateless(name = "myejb")

    public class EJB_A implements Interface_EJB_A
    {
        @EJB
        private EJB_B ejb_b;

        @EJB
        private EJB_C ejb_c;

    public String method()
    {

    ejb_b.call();
    ejb_c.call();

    }

    ...
    }
```

How does entity manager injected in EJB_C knows there's is a transaction ongoing
if it knows nothing about the exsistence of the EntityManager injected in EJB_B ?

It's this king of container added magic I'm having hard time to grasp...

Answer (score 0):

The container internally uses a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable to store the transaction. And the persistence context used by the entity managers is synchronized to this transaction. So the work done by EJBs A, B and C are both linked to the same persistence context, and done in the same transaction.

The specifications say:

> By default, a container-managed persistence context is of SynchronizationType.SYNCHRONIZED and is automatically joined to the current transaction.

[...]

> The application can obtain a container-managed entity manager with transaction-scoped persistence context by injection or direct lookup in the JNDI namespace. The persistence context type for the entity manager is defaulted or defined as PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION.
>
> A new persistence context begins when the container-managed entity manager is invoked[82] in the scope of an active JTA transaction, and there is no current persistence context already associated with the JTA transaction. The persistence context is created and then associated with the JTA transaction.

[...]

> As described in section 7.1, a single persistence context may correspond to one or more JTA entity manager instances (all associated with the same entity manager factory[84]).
>   The persistence context is propagated across the entity manager instances as the JTA transaction is propagated.